# The wavelength of a photon after pair production

Tags: quantum-mechanics, pair-production

The book that I am using says that the total energy of an electron positron pair before they happen to collide is equal to $$ 2mc^² + 2K.E$$ where K.E is kinetic energy. They then say that this energy will be transformed into energy of two photons which have Sacha. Wavelength of:

$$\lambda = hc/mc^2 +K.E.$$  where h is Planck's constant and c is the speed of light. The thing is I think there is a typo here and the equation should be instead: 
$$\lambda = hc/(mc^2 +K.E.)$$. Is that right?

Comment: you are asking in the question about annihilation of electron positron, and the title of  production ?

Comment: @annav yes it is actually about annihilation and pair production together as written in the question.

Comment: pair production needs a nuclear field for conservation of momentum.Only if you assume the nuclear transfer is small: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#Energy_transfer

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that is right. The equation in the book has wrong dimensions.

hc/(mc^2) has dimensions of length, while KE has dimensions of Energy, you can't add them.

The equation you wrote is Correct.